# PHP / mysql join

Tags: php, mysql

I  need  to  get 3 tables's values , from first I  need to get aff_id where v_id = 5 , from second I  need to get user id where aff_id = first's aff_id , and from third I  need  to  get username , email , id where id = second's aff_id . I can't  write correct  mysql  query to  get  data , please , help  me  to  get it . Here is  my wrong  code

```
SELECT * FROM wp_vendor_affiliates WHERE vendor_id = 21 LEFT JOIN wp_affiliate_wp_affiliates

 SELECT wp_vendor_affiliates.affiliate_id , 
wp_affiliate_wp_affiliates.user_id
FROM wp_vendor_affiliates

INNER JOIN wp_affiliate_wp_affiliates INNER JOIN
```

Please , hetp  me  , and  correct  my query   . Thanks  fot  helping and  for  support

Comment: Do you want a random, syntactically correct query, or do you want to solve a specific problem. If the latter, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$id1 = 5;
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE v_id='{$id1}'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$id2 = $row1['aff_id'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE aff_id='{$id2}'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$id3 = $row2['aff_id'];

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE id='{$id3}'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
$id2 = $row3['aff_id'];
```

Here $con is the connection to your database

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data_base");
```

I used here connection to the localhost. which you'd have to change most certainly. It's a bit long but basic